# Python34.dll is missing

Tags: python, dll, cython

I had created an application in Python and then I tried to make an executable from it.
Works well in Ubuntu and Windows **but** only when on this system I have Python installed.
In other case (Tried only for Win) I get the error that "The application can't start because python34.dll is missing"

What I do (filename is **curr.py**, also I have **icon.res** for icon):

1. `python C:\Python34\Scripts\cython-script.py --embed curr.py`
2. in curr.c replace **wmain** by **main** (without doing it app won't be compiled at all)
3. `gcc curr.c -o curr.exe -IC:\Python34\include -LC:\Python34\libs icon.res -lpython34 -mwindows --static`

Of course, If I copy python34.dll to the app's folder everything is OK. 
Do I have another way?

Comment: Is the directory containing python34.dll in %PATH%?

Comment: Of course, there is.

Comment: I could see something like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) being useful.

Comment: py2exe copies python34.dll, altogether with bunch of additional files. I suppose, there is no way to "pack" python34.dll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimal set of files required to distribute an embed-Cython-compiled code and make it work on any machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390978/minimal-set-of-files-required-to-distribute-an-embed-cython-compiled-code-and-ma)

Answer (score 0):

Just installed **PyInstaller** - it has the option to compile to one file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in My case is

[download](https://developer.blender.org/F96208)  pyhton34.dll and paste it into 
C:\Windows\System32 or 
C:\Windows\syswow64,  one of will definitely work.

Comment: Amazing and now running 34