# Minimal set of files required to distribute an embed-Cython-compiled code and make it work on any machine

Tags: python, windows, compilation, cython, cx-freeze

TL;DR: how to use Cython as a distribution method instead of Py2exe, cx_freeze, pyinstaller, etc.

---

Following [Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython), I'd like to see how it could be possible to distribute a Python program to any Windows user (who doesn't have Python already installed on his machine) by compiling it first with Cython `--embed`.

Let's use a `test.py`:

```
import json
print(json.dumps({'key': 'hello world'}))
```

and compile it:

```
cython test.py --embed
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cl test.c /I C:\Python37\include /link C:\Python37\libs\python37.lib
```

It works and produces a 140KB `test.exe` executable.

Running `test.exe` on another machine doesn't work out-of-the-box, it requires:

- python37.dll in the same folder
- to install the usual [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) file

Even with this, it still does not work <sup>(screenshot below instead of copy/paste because I didn't manage the copy/paste in the VM - off topic here)</sup>:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

[image]

**Question: what is the minimal set of files required to distribute an `--embed`-Cython-compiled code and make it work on any machine (without Python previously installed on it)?**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857449/importerror-after-cython-embed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After further research (I tried in an empty Win 7 x64 bit VM, without any VCredist previously installed), it seems that these files are enough:

- the program itself, `test.exe` (produced by `cython --embed` and compilation with `cl.exe`)
- `python37.dll`
- `python37.zip` coming from packages named *"Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file"* in https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- `vcruntime140.dll`, as mentioned in [Can I bundle the Visual Studio 2015 C++ Redistributable DLL's with my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097193/can-i-bundle-the-visual-studio-2015-c-redistributable-dlls-with-my-applicatio) or ask the user to install [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) before
- `ucrtbase.dll`
- more than 30 files `api-ms-win-*.dll` were required too; if not you will have the following error:

  > ... api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing ...

Notes:

- if you require another library, like `pygame`, just copy/paste the folder from `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pygame` seems to work
- for me, concrt140.dll, msvcp140.dll, vccorlib140.dll did not seem necessary

Useful to test all this: [Prevent a Python-embedded to look in my default path C:\Python38 for modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73058076/prevent-a-python-embedded-to-look-in-my-default-path-c-python38-for-modules).